# How to FIX this message in ASP.NET (Visual Studio) with my query?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

This is my script in SQL but when I try use a form view in ASP.NET (visual studio). I worked with SQL Server Management Studio

```
CREATE TABLE [odl].[MaterialDetail]
(
    [Material] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [PlantID] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [LabelPos] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [UseProdLabel] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [UseContLabel] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [UseTote] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [COO] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [LabelsPerCont] [decimal](9, 2) NOT NULL,
    [TareWeight] [decimal](9, 2) NOT NULL,
    [AltTareWeight] [decimal](9, 2) NOT NULL,
    [ModDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [CreateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [rowguid] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_MaterialDetail] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Material] ASC,
    [PlantID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [odl].[MaterialDetail] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_MaterialDetail_Material]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [Material]
GO

ALTER TABLE [odl].[MaterialDetail] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_MaterialDetail_PlantID]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [PlantID]
GO

ALTER TABLE [odl].[MaterialDetail] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_MaterialDetail_LabelPos]  DEFAULT ('0') FOR [LabelPos]
GO

ALTER TABLE [odl].[MaterialDetail] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_MaterialDetail_UseProdLabel]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [UseProdLabel]
GO

ALTER TABLE [odl].[MaterialDetail] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_MaterialDetail_UseContLabel]  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [UseContLabel]
GO

ALTER TABLE [odl].[MaterialDetail] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_MaterialDetail_UseTote]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [UseTote]
GO

ALTER TABLE [odl].[MaterialDetail] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_MaterialDetail_COO]  DEFAULT ('') FOR [COO]
GO

ALTER TABLE [odl].[MaterialDetail] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_MaterialDetail_LabelPerCont]  DEFAULT ((2)) FOR [LabelsPerCont]
GO

ALTER TABLE [odl].[MaterialDetail] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_MaterialDetail_TareWeight]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [TareWeight]
GO

ALTER TABLE [odl].[MaterialDetail] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_MaterialDetail_AltTareWeight]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [AltTareWeight]
GO

ALTER TABLE [odl].[MaterialDetail] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_MaterialDetail_ModDate]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [ModDate]
GO

ALTER TABLE [odl].[MaterialDetail] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_MaterialDetail_CreateDate]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [CreateDate]
GO

ALTER TABLE [odl].[MaterialDetail] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_MaterialDetail_rowguid]  DEFAULT (newsequentialid()) FOR [rowguid]
GO
```

I get this error in the moment when i try test my query

> There was an error executing the query. Please check the syntax of
>   the command and if, present, the types and values of the parameters
>   and ensure they are correct Invalid object name 'MaterialDetail'

Comment: What is your DB? Sql?

Comment: Yes, I am sorry, I am working with SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: The above query working fine with my Sql server 2008 R2. Do you have schema named "odl"?

Comment: Yeah, the problem is when i try to work with the DB on form view in visual studio

Comment: Please update your select query here.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, that SQL code doesn't produce any data or results. It just sets up a brand new empty table. I don't know what you'd expect your form-view to show, because there's not data here.

Secondly, if the table *already* exists in the database, or if the constraints you are adding already exist, I would expect this code to throw an error when run for a second time, because you are trying to create an object that already exists.

Finally, that SQL makes extensive use of the `GO` separator. `GO` is **not** a part of the SQL language. It is a feature of Sql Server Management Studio that is used for separating queries into different batches. The `GO` keyword is never sent to the database server, and Sql Server wouldn't know what to do with it if it were.